# Datetime format is 'mm-dd-yyyy' when getting while using SqlDataAdapter but if I run the same query in ms sql then its 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know the question is a bit confusing. Please let me elaborate.

Suppose

1. I have a table student master which has a column DOB
2. I have inserted a record and in DOB I have inserted '1991-01-01'
3. running select statement from sql server is returning date in the same format as it is inserted '1991-01-01' but when I am running the same query from C# using `SqlDataAdapter` then its returning date as '01-01-1991'

Can anyone explain why it is happening and is there any way to fetch the date in same format as it is inserted.

**Query**

Is it possible to get the DateTime using SqlDataAdapter as it was inserted?

P.S: column data type is `Datetime`

Comment: what type is the column?

Comment: `DateTime` @DanielA.White

Comment: That probably happens because of your culture - C# uses the current OS culture, while Management Studio uses the more standard ISO format.

Comment: there's no formatting information associated with that type. can you do the formatting after the fact

Comment: @EugenePodskal @DanielA.White is there a way to set `yyyy-MMM-dd` to default in stead of formatting every column in select statement?

Comment: @VikasBansal I am sure that such question has been already asked and answered. Though I am not sure that it is a good idea to use solutions that propose modifying current culture's DateTime format.

Comment: Well - you could format the datetime in your select, but you really shouldn't need to worry about the display in management studio, as it's just ... well management studio

Comment: C# has many different formats built into DataTime class.  For example : ToLongDateString(),ToLongTimeString(),ToShortDateString(),ToShortTimeString(),ToString(),ToString(IFormatProvider provider),ToString(string format),ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider).  Using a format,a provider, or a different property will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's separate the wheat from the chaff :)

if for your needs meaningful is data type (`datetime` in this case), then formatting does not matter at all. All layers which will exchange or process the data will use data type information for that.

But

if the meaningful part is formatting, i.e. string representation of the data, then you need to consider the appropriate settings of UI tools you use to display your data. SSMS, for example, uses regional settings for that. If you need to visualize data in the identical manner, so you need the identical strings, you should take care of formatting by your self or in another words, you need to convert your datetime data to string in the same way in all places where you need it.

In `T-SQL`, for example, you could use [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) functions for formatting your data in a format you need.

Comment: May we retrieve all the DateTime values in `yyyy-MMM-dd` format by default? Right now, its `dd-MMM-yyyy` when I use `select` statement. I understand what you are saying is right but for now, I need a workaround so that I can get some time to alter all the queries and set date time format while retrieving. I can not change the culture settings of the user

Comment: You do not understand the idea :) Formatting does not related to data type at all. Formatting applies on data only when you trying to SEE it in  some UI. So, if Sql Server passes some `datetime` value to the upper level (to C# code for example), this layer will process the value as `datetime`.

Comment: Try to explicitly cast the data as `datetime` in the C# code

Answer (score 1):

If you can't match up the "Cultures" between the SQL Server and the machine you're building the application on (and, in fact, you cannot rely on that really if you're application is going to be deployed to other machines!), then the cheap and quick way round it is to run your date returns through a parse function such as this:

```
    private string FncFormatDate(string date)
    {
        DateTime formattedDate;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out formattedDate))
        {
            return formattedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid date";
        }
    }
```

I hope this answers your question.